# How do I create a calculated column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[image]

I want to create a new column, **BSI**.

The formula:

**BSI = ln((1+nPd)/(1+nNd))**

- d = date
- nP: sum of Positive Predictions
- nN: sum of Negative Predictions

In essence,

- I want to group the **pred_rate** column by **date**,
- Get the sum of **positive predictions (1)** and **negative predictions (0)** for each group
- Perform the **BSI** calculation as a new column in the data

The data frame in the image is a snippet of a larger one.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so the community knows your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Having a df as such:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date':[
             '2019-12-14'
            ,'2019-12-14'
            ,'2019-12-15'
            ,'2019-12-15'
            ,'2019-12-15'
            ,'2019-12-16'
            ,'2019-12-16'
            ,'2019-12-16'
            ,'2019-12-16'
        ],
        'rate':[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
        'pred_rate':[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
    }
)
```

```
    date        rate    pred_rate
0   2019-12-14  0       0
1   2019-12-14  0       1
2   2019-12-15  1       1
3   2019-12-15  0       0
4   2019-12-15  0       0
5   2019-12-16  1       0
6   2019-12-16  0       1
7   2019-12-16  1       1
8   2019-12-16  0       1
```

If you want a new 'grouped' dataframe:

```
df.groupby('date').agg(
    BSI =('pred_rate',
        lambda x: np.log(
            np.divide(
                (1+x.eq(1).sum()),
                (1+x.eq(0).sum())
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Resulting in something like:

```
            BSI
date    
2019-12-14  0.000000
2019-12-15  -0.405465
2019-12-16  0.693147
```

Or if you want it in your existing dataframe:

```
df['BSI'] = df.groupby('date').pred_rate.transform(
        lambda x: np.log(
            np.divide(
                (1+x.eq(1).sum()),
                (1+x.eq(0).sum())
            )
        )
    )
```

Resulting in something like:

```
    date        rate    pred_rate   BSI
0   2019-12-14  0       0           0.000000
1   2019-12-14  0       1           0.000000
2   2019-12-15  1       1           -0.405465
3   2019-12-15  0       0           -0.405465
4   2019-12-15  0       0           -0.405465
5   2019-12-16  1       0           0.693147
6   2019-12-16  0       1           0.693147
7   2019-12-16  1       1           0.693147
8   2019-12-16  0       1           0.693147
```